# How to make a parallelogram on python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a parallelogram out of the rectangle I already have but I'm not sure how to add spaces in front of the characters. My code is:

```
l=int(input("Enter the lenght of the rectangle: "))
w=int(input("Enter the width: "))
c=str(input("Enter the character: "))
def print_rect(l, w, c):  
    for a in range(w):  
        print(l*c)  
print_rect(l, w, c)
```

I have tried

```
 for n in range(l-1)  
 print("")`
```

but I'm not sure how to implement it or if it actually will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define n.
For the spaces, use you loop counter:

```
def print_rect(l, w, c):
    for a in range(w):
        print(a*" ", l*c)
```

Comment: Finally, I think you switched you length and width.

Comment: It was supposed to be l*c, not n*c, sorry I was messing with it to get the parallelogram working and I didn't fix it. Also, that just added one space in front. I'm trying to make it that if I have a width of 5, the first line has 4 blank spaces, the 2nd has 3 and so on.

Comment: Fine -- then just alter the 'a' in _a*" "_ to the value you want.  In my environment, it did a very nice rectangle.  If you're having trouble, please update your code and output in the main question.

Comment: I don't need to make a rectangle, I need to make a parallelogram. The code I have up there already makes a rectangle. Also, the code works so that the rectangle is made differently depending on what the user inputs, so I can't just substitute 'a' to a fixed value.

Comment: Sorry; I meant to type that "it made a very nice parallelogram."  You don't substitute a fixed value; you substitute the expression you need.  It's basic algebra.  For instance, if I tell you that the parallelogram is 50 units high and 100 wide, how many spaces do you need in front of the 3rd line of output?  How did you figure that out?  Write that expression for the computer.

Comment: Sorry, I was implementing the code wrong and messed up on the print function so it only showed one space. Now I have the parallelogram. thank you. One last question though, what do I need to do in order to do this in reverse, Like the last line is the one that has no blank spaces?

Comment: See my previous comment -- and remember to put parentheses around the expression you derive, such as print ((a+7)*" ", length*c)